# Something is unsetting my database class

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm storing sessions in a MySQL database.

I've a SessionManager class which has multiple functions. However, somewhere in the class, my database class is being unloaded, and I can't seem to find out why.

I tested to see if the class exists using:

```
echo (class_exists('database') === TRUE ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

This is the function which is producing a fatal error telling me that the class `database` is not found. Note that test above returns true where the test is located in the `__construct` and fails specifically in this method:

```
public static function writeSession($sessionId, $sessionData)
{
    $sessionId = session_id();
    session_write_close();
    session_id($sessionId);
    $expiry = time() + ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') - 1;
    $sessionId = database::getInstance()->real_escape_string($sessionId);
    $sessionData = database::getInstance()->real_escape_string($sessionData);
    $result = database::getInstance()->query("SELECT sessionid FROM sessions WHERE sessionid='$sessionId'");
    ($result->num_rows > 0) ?
        database::getInstance()->query("UPDATE sessions SET sessionid='$sessionId',expiry='$expiry',sessiondata= '$sessionData' WHERE sessionid='$sessionId'")
        : database::getInstance()->query("INSERT INTO sessions (sessionid,expiry,sessiondata) VALUES ('$sessionId','$expiry','$sessionData')") ;
}
```

Even if I try to instantiate a new object of database, the class is not found, it's as if it disappears.

The class works, and is fine in the previous method:

```
  public static function readSession($sessionId)
{

    $sessionId = session_id();
    $sessionId = database::getInstance()->real_escape_string($sessionId);
    $time = time();
    $result = database::getInstance()->query("SELECT sessiondata FROM sessions WHERE sessionid='$sessionId' AND expiry > $time");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array();
        return $row['sessiondata'];
    }
    return "";
}
```

Can anyone see what's going on here?

Comment: `public static` ? meaning it can by pass the constructor

Comment: Singletons **and** `mysql_*()`? No offence mate, but you deserve every bit of headache you're having.

Comment: @ajreal, yes, they're only public because there are other interactions with the session handlers.

Comment: no, i mean the `static`, and this `database::getInstance()`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha there's no use of `mysql_` functions, only MySQLi in the database class. Why am I using Singletons? It's keeping the code clean than having to initiate a new database object on every single function.

Comment: @Shamil You may want to look into dependency injection here.

Comment: @ajreal it being there shouldn't be making a difference. However, yes, it would be passable by the constructor. Unless you want to re initialise the class everytime you wanted to use something in the manager.

Comment: @Shamil Honest question: do you test your code?

Comment: @Shamil: You initialize a `DatabaseFactory` at the bootstrap stage, and pass it on to all of the classes and other factories, when a class needs a database, it would have the factory create that for it.

Comment: @PeeHaa, yes, it is working locally and not remotely.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Hmm, lemme look into it

Comment: @Shamil: You missed the point of "Testing" He probably meant "Unit Testing".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, I haven't done unit testing on this yet - it's too early on - but I've found something interesting - a discrepancy between how MySQL handles queries on my local and remote machine. The application works again, but now I'm going to have to find out why my MySQL server is being either lenient or the remote is being strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two major points at the beginning:

1. The fatal error is not lying. So the `database` class is missing (not unset) at some (and that) point.
2. You make use of static methods in the session class. That only needs the session class to exist when the function in question is called. There is nothing set-up in any way that ensures the `database` class definition is actually loaded.

Which leads to the solution that you should require the `database` class definition for that function call. Put that in, and the `database` class is defined. Actually I don't understand about which part you wonder that much in your question.

Classes and especially static functions are rather straight forward, you could also replace them with standard functions to a certain degree which might make your type of usage more visible and more straight forward. Don't use language features you don't feel common with until you do.

Comment: Hi @hakre, thanks :) I didn't think that it was lying, it just didn't occur to me that it was missing as such. A lot of the functions were static because they were needed to be called without instantiating the whole session object again. I'm slowly moving things out of this script into more appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

`class_exists()` checks if your class can be loaded. If it returns false, your class code can not be located.

If you use autoloading, you have to check your autoloader.

If you don't, you have to add a `require_once "Path/To/The/File/With/The/Code/For/The/DatabaseClass.php` (with the path to the file with the class code).

Comment: I am using an autoloader, however, I assume that the class is loading correctly, given that it is not failing in the previous function. Given that `class_exists()`, is false for some but not all functions inside the file, what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Though this probably doesn't really answer the question, I found two interesting things.

1, APC was causing an issue with my database class, I haven't found the reason yet though. I've globally disabled this on the server pending investigation.

2, Check that MySQL configs are indeed the same, both handle queries in the same manner etc.